# Constructor Vacio de Java a Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, constructor

Hola tengo un contructor en Java es el siguiente:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
    public BaseResponse() {
    }

    @SerializedName("data")
    public T data;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("mensaje")
    public String mensaje;
    @SerializedName("mensajeDeveloper")
    public String mensajeDeveloper;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public String getMensajeDeveloper() {
        return mensajeDeveloper;
    }
}
```

Aquí se le puede poner un constructor vacío `public BaseResponse() {}` y posteriormente puedo llamarlo así

```
private BaseResponse baseResponse = new BaseResponse();
```

Este código lo he llevado a kotlin y es el siguiente pero no tengo en constructor vacío(En kotlin estoy utilizando data class):

```
data class BaseResponse<T>(

    @SerializedName("Data")
    val data: T,
    @SerializedName("Status")
    val status: Int,
    @SerializedName("Mensaje")
    val mensaje: String,
    @SerializedName("MensajeDeveloper")
    val mensajeDeveloper: String,
    @SerializedName("Result")
    val result: Boolean,
    var tipo: String,
    var tipoNumero: Int
)
```

Estoy tratando de usar el constructor vacío pero me sale el error `Property getter or setter expected`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de introducir el constructor vacío?

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Kotlin el constructor se declara junto con la clase. Todo lo que pusiste dentro de los paréntesis son sus parámetros. Tal vez la sintaxis completa te ayude a identificarlo mejor:

```
data class BaseResponse<T> public constructor(
    @SerializedName("Data")
    val data: T,
    ...
)
```

Si no quieres que reciba argumentos, simplemente no escribas los paréntesis

```
class BaseResponse<T> {
    @SerializedName("Data")
    var data: T? = null
    ...
}
```

A diferencia de Java, las propiedades no tienen el valor `null` por defecto, entonces debes asignarle su valor explícitamente.

Otra opción que te puede servir es mantener el constructor que tienes pero agregarle default values a todos los argumentos.

```
data class BaseResponse<T> (
    @SerializedName("Data")
    var data: T? = null,
    ...
)
```

Esto también te permite instanciar la clase sin usar argumentos pero está bastante más alejado de lo que tenías en Java.

De qualquier forma, el error que se ve en la imagen no tiene nada que ver con el constructor de la clase. Simplemente es un error de sintaxis. Se supone que a la derecha del `:` va la declaración del tipo, no puedes crear objetos ahí. Esta línea

```
private var requerimientos : MutableLiveData<BaseResponse<RequerimientoData>>()
```

es equivalente a hacer esto en Java

```
final new MutableLiveData<BaseResponse<RequerimientoData>>() requerimientos;
```

Lo cual, por supuesto, tampoco es válido.

Independientemente de cual sea el constructor de `BaseResponse`, funcionará correctamente si reemplazas los dos puntos por un `=`

```
private var requerimientos = MutableLiveData<BaseResponse<RequerimientoData>>()
```